Kohya_ss Colab fine tune Jax error / torch compatibility
The finetune notebook worked previously with !pip install "jax[cuda12_pip]==0.4.23" -f https://storage.googleapis.com/jax-releases/jax_cuda_releases.html
Now this no longer works. I have captured the output of the colab cells for both when it worked and when it doesn't.
I've confirmed Colab has brokenthe notebook as when rolling it back with colab use fallback it works.
Here are the requirements (frozen packages after the fix applied) first from the working version then from the broken.
Working:
Cython==3.0.11
Flask==2.2.5
GDAL==3.6.4
Markdown==3.7
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
PyDrive==1.3.1
PyDrive2==1.20.0
PyJWT==2.9.0
PyOpenGL==3.1.7
PySocks==1.7.1
PyYAML==6.0.2
SQLAlchemy==2.0.35
Send2Trash==1.8.3
Sphinx==5.0.2
StrEnum==0.4.15
absl-py==1.4.0
accelerate==0.34.2
aiohappyeyeballs==2.4.0
aiohttp==3.10.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
alabaster==0.7.16
albucore==0.0.16
albumentations==1.4.15
altair==4.2.2
annotated-types==0.7.0
anyio==3.7.1
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
array-record==0.5.1
arviz==0.19.0
astropy==6.1.3
astropy-iers-data==0.2024.9.16.0.32.21
astunparse==1.6.3
async-timeout==4.0.3
atpublic==4.1.0
attrs==24.2.0
audioread==3.0.1
autograd==1.7.0
babel==2.16.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bidict==0.23.1
bigframes==1.17.0
bigquery-magics==0.2.0
bleach==6.1.0
blis==0.7.11
blosc2==2.0.0
bokeh==3.4.3
bqplot==0.12.43
branca==0.7.2
build==1.2.2
cachecontrol==0.14.0
cachetools==5.5.0
catalogue==2.0.10
certifi==2024.8.30
cffi==1.17.1
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
chex==0.1.86
clarabel==0.9.0
click==8.1.7
cloudpathlib==0.19.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
cmake==3.30.3
cmdstanpy==1.2.4
colorcet==3.1.0
colorlover==0.3.0
colour==0.1.5
community==1.0.0b1
confection==0.1.5
cons==0.4.6
contextlib2==21.6.0
contourpy==1.3.0
cryptography==43.0.1
cuda-python==12.2.1
cudf-cu12==24.4.1
cufflinks==0.17.3
cupy-cuda12x==12.2.0
cvxopt==1.3.2
cvxpy==1.5.3
cycler==0.12.1
cymem==2.0.8
dask==2024.8.0
datascience==0.17.6
db-dtypes==1.3.0
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
distributed==2024.8.0
dlib==19.24.2
dm-tree==0.1.8
docstring-parser==0.16
docutils==0.18.1
dopamine-rl==4.0.9
duckdb==1.1.0
earthengine-api==1.0.0
easydict==1.13
ecos==2.0.14
editdistance==0.8.1
eerepr==0.0.4
einops==0.8.0
en-core-web-sm==3.7.1
entrypoints==0.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
etils==1.9.4
etuples==0.3.9
eval-type-backport==0.2.0
exceptiongroup==1.2.2
fastai==2.7.17
fastcore==1.7.8
fastdownload==0.0.7
fastjsonschema==2.20.0
fastprogress==1.0.3
fastrlock==0.8.2
filelock==3.16.1
firebase-admin==6.5.0
flatbuffers==24.3.25
flax==0.8.4
folium==0.17.0
fonttools==4.53.1
frozendict==2.4.4
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.6.1
future==1.0.0
gast==0.6.0
gcsfs==2024.6.1
gdown==5.2.0
geemap==0.34.2
gensim==4.3.3
geocoder==1.38.1
geographiclib==2.0
geopandas==1.0.1
geopy==2.4.1
gin-config==0.5.0
glob2==0.7
google==2.0.3
google-ai-generativelanguage==0.6.6
google-api-core==2.19.2
google-api-python-client==2.137.0
google-auth==2.27.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.1
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.67.1
google-cloud-bigquery==3.25.0
google-cloud-bigquery-connection==1.15.5
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.26.0
google-cloud-bigtable==2.26.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-datastore==2.19.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.16.1
google-cloud-functions==1.16.5
google-cloud-iam==2.15.2
google-cloud-language==2.13.4
google-cloud-pubsub==2.23.1
google-cloud-resource-manager==1.12.5
google-cloud-storage==2.8.0
google-cloud-translate==3.15.5
google-colab==1.0.0
google-crc32c==1.6.0
google-generativeai==0.7.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==2.7.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.65.0
googledrivedownloader==0.4
graphviz==0.20.3
greenlet==3.1.0
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.13.1
grpcio==1.64.1
grpcio-status==1.48.2
gspread==6.0.2
gspread-dataframe==3.3.1
gym==0.25.2
gym-notices==0.0.8
h5netcdf==1.3.0
h5py==3.11.0
holidays==0.57
holoviews==1.19.1
html5lib==1.1
httpimport==1.4.0
httplib2==0.22.0
huggingface-hub==0.24.7
humanize==4.10.0
hyperopt==0.2.7
ibis-framework==8.0.0
idna==3.10
imageio==2.35.1
imageio-ffmpeg==0.5.1
imagesize==1.4.1
imbalanced-learn==0.12.3
imgaug==0.4.0
immutabledict==4.2.0
importlib-metadata==8.5.0
importlib-resources==6.4.5
imutils==0.5.4
inflect==7.4.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
intel-cmplr-lib-ur==2024.2.1
intel-openmp==2024.2.1
ipyevents==2.0.2
ipyfilechooser==0.6.0
ipykernel==5.5.6
ipyleaflet==0.19.2
ipyparallel==8.8.0
ipython==7.34.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipython-sql==0.5.0
ipytree==0.2.2
ipywidgets==7.7.1
itsdangerous==2.2.0
jax==0.4.26
jaxlib==0.4.26+cuda12.cudnn89
jellyfish==1.1.0
jieba==0.42.1
jinja2==3.1.4
joblib==1.4.2
jsonpickle==3.3.0
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==5.7.2
jupyter-leaflet==0.19.2
jupyter-server==1.24.0
jupyterlab-pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.13
kaggle==1.6.17
kagglehub==0.3.0
keras==3.4.1
kiwisolver==1.4.7
langcodes==3.4.0
language-data==1.2.0
lazy-loader==0.4
libclang==18.1.1
librosa==0.10.2.post1
lightgbm==4.5.0
linkify-it-py==2.0.3
llvmlite==0.43.0
locket==1.0.0
logical-unification==0.4.6
lxml==4.9.4
marisa-trie==1.2.0
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
matplotlib==3.7.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
matplotlib-venn==1.1.1
mdit-py-plugins==0.4.2
mdurl==0.1.2
miniKanren==1.0.3
missingno==0.5.2
mistune==0.8.4
mizani==0.11.4
mkl==2024.2.2
ml-dtypes==0.4.1
mlxtend==0.23.1
more-itertools==10.5.0
moviepy==1.0.3
mpmath==1.3.0
msgpack==1.0.8
multidict==6.1.0
multipledispatch==1.0.0
multitasking==0.0.11
murmurhash==1.0.10
music21==9.1.0
namex==0.0.8
natsort==8.4.0
nbclassic==1.1.0
nbclient==0.10.0
nbconvert==6.5.4
nbformat==5.10.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
networkx==3.3
nibabel==5.2.1
nltk==3.8.1
notebook==6.5.5
notebook-shim==0.2.4
numba==0.60.0
numexpr==2.10.1
numpy==1.26.4
nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.23.4
nvtx==0.2.10
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python==4.10.0.84
opencv-python==4.10.0.84
opencv-python-headless==4.10.0.84
openpyxl==3.1.5
opt-einsum==3.3.0
optax==0.2.2
optree==0.12.1
orbax-checkpoint==0.6.4
osqp==0.6.7.post0
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.1.4
pandas-datareader==0.10.0
pandas-gbq==0.23.1
pandas-stubs==2.1.4.231227
pandocfilters==1.5.1
panel==1.4.5
param==2.1.1
parso==0.8.4
parsy==2.1
partd==1.4.2
pathlib==1.0.1
patsy==0.5.6
peewee==3.17.6
pexpect==4.9.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pillow==10.4.0
pip==24.1.2
pip-tools==7.4.1
platformdirs==4.3.6
plotly==5.24.1
plotnine==0.13.6
pluggy==1.5.0
polars==1.6.0
pooch==1.8.2
portpicker==1.5.2
prefetch-generator==1.0.3
preshed==3.0.9
prettytable==3.11.0
proglog==0.1.10
progressbar2==4.5.0
prometheus-client==0.20.0
promise==2.3
prompt-toolkit==3.0.47
prophet==1.1.5
proto-plus==1.24.0
protobuf==3.20.3
psutil==5.9.5
psycopg2==2.9.9
ptyprocess==0.7.0
py4j==0.10.9.7
pyOpenSSL==24.2.1
py-cpuinfo==9.0.0
pyarrow==14.0.2
pyarrow-hotfix==0.6
pyasn1==0.6.1
pyasn1-modules==0.4.1
pycocotools==2.0.8
pycparser==2.22
pydantic==2.9.2
pydantic-core==2.23.4
pydata-google-auth==1.8.2
pydot==3.0.1
pydot-ng==2.0.0
pydotplus==2.0.2
pyerfa==2.0.1.4
pygame==2.6.0
pygments==2.18.0
pymc==5.16.2
pymystem3==0.2.0
pynvjitlink-cu12==0.3.0
pyogrio==0.9.0
pyparsing==3.1.4
pyperclip==1.9.0
pyproj==3.6.1
pyproject-hooks==1.1.0
pyshp==2.3.1
pytensor==2.25.4
pytest==7.4.4
python-apt==2.4.0
python-box==7.2.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-louvain==0.16
python-slugify==8.0.4
python-utils==3.8.2
pytz==2024.2
pyviz-comms==3.0.3
pyzmq==24.0.1
qdldl==0.1.7.post4
ratelim==0.1.6
referencing==0.35.1
regex==2024.9.11
requests==2.32.3
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
requirements-parser==0.9.0
rich==13.8.1
rmm-cu12==24.4.0
rpds-py==0.20.0
rpy2==3.4.2
rsa==4.9
safetensors==0.4.5
scikit-image==0.24.0
scikit-learn==1.5.2
scipy==1.13.1
scooby==0.10.0
scs==3.2.7
seaborn==0.13.1
sentencepiece==0.2.0
setuptools==71.0.4
shapely==2.0.6
shellingham==1.5.4
simple-parsing==0.1.6
six==1.16.0
sklearn-pandas==2.2.0
smart-open==7.0.4
sniffio==1.3.1
snowballstemmer==2.2.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soundfile==0.12.1
soupsieve==2.6
soxr==0.5.0.post1
spacy==3.7.6
spacy-legacy==3.0.12
spacy-loggers==1.0.5
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.1.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==2.0.0
sqlglot==20.11.0
sqlparse==0.5.1
srsly==2.4.8
stanio==0.5.1
statsmodels==0.14.3
sympy==1.13.3
tables==3.8.0
tabulate==0.9.0
tbb==2021.13.1
tblib==3.0.0
tenacity==9.0.0
tensorboard==2.17.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow==2.17.0
tensorflow-datasets==4.9.6
tensorflow-hub==0.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.37.1
tensorflow-metadata==1.15.0
tensorflow-probability==0.24.0
tensorstore==0.1.65
termcolor==2.4.0
terminado==0.18.1
text-unidecode==1.3
textblob==0.17.1
tf-keras==2.17.0
tf-slim==1.1.0
thinc==8.2.5
threadpoolctl==3.5.0
tifffile==2024.8.30
tinycss2==1.3.0
tokenizers==0.19.1
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
toolz==0.12.1
torch==2.4.1+cu121
torchaudio==2.4.1+cu121
torchsummary==1.5.1
torchvision==0.19.1+cu121
tornado==6.3.3
tqdm==4.66.5
traitlets==5.7.1
traittypes==0.2.1
transformers==4.44.2
tweepy==4.14.0
typeguard==4.3.0
typer==0.12.5
types-pytz==2024.2.0.20240913
types-setuptools==75.1.0.20240917
typing-extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
tzlocal==5.2
uc-micro-py==1.0.3
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==2.2.3
vega-datasets==0.9.0
wasabi==1.1.3
wcwidth==0.2.13
weasel==0.4.1
webcolors==24.8.0
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.8.0
werkzeug==3.0.4
wheel==0.44.0
widgetsnbextension==3.6.9
wordcloud==1.9.3
wrapt==1.16.0
xarray==2024.9.0
xarray-einstats==0.8.0
xgboost==2.1.1
xlrd==2.0.1
xyzservices==2024.9.0
yarl==1.11.1
yellowbrick==1.5
yfinance==0.2.43
zict==3.0.0
zipp==3.20.2
PyGObject==3.42.1
SecretStorage==3.3.1
blinker==1.4
dbus-python==1.2.18
distro==1.7.0
jeepney==0.7.1
keyring==23.5.0
launchpadlib==1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.4
lazr.uri==1.0.6
wadllib==1.3.6
autocommand==2.2.2
backports.tarfile==1.2.0
jaraco.context==5.3.0
jaraco.functools==4.0.1
jaraco.text==3.12.1
ordered-set==4.1.0

Not working:
Cython==3.0.11
Flask==2.2.5
GDAL==3.6.4
Markdown==3.7
MarkupSafe==2.1.5
PyDrive==1.3.1
PyDrive2==1.20.0
PyJWT==2.9.0
PyOpenGL==3.1.7
PySocks==1.7.1
PyYAML==6.0.2
SQLAlchemy==2.0.35
Send2Trash==1.8.3
Sphinx==5.0.2
StrEnum==0.4.15
absl-py==1.4.0
accelerate==0.34.2
aiohappyeyeballs==2.4.0
aiohttp==3.10.5
aiosignal==1.3.1
alabaster==0.7.16
albucore==0.0.16
albumentations==1.4.15
altair==4.2.2
annotated-types==0.7.0
anyio==3.7.1
argon2-cffi==23.1.0
argon2-cffi-bindings==21.2.0
array-record==0.5.1
arviz==0.19.0
astropy==6.1.3
astropy-iers-data==0.2024.9.16.0.32.21
astunparse==1.6.3
async-timeout==4.0.3
atpublic==4.1.0
attrs==24.2.0
audioread==3.0.1
autograd==1.7.0
babel==2.16.0
backcall==0.2.0
beautifulsoup4==4.12.3
bigframes==1.18.0
bigquery-magics==0.2.0
bleach==6.1.0
blis==0.7.11
blosc2==2.0.0
bokeh==3.4.3
bqplot==0.12.43
branca==0.7.2
build==1.2.2
cachecontrol==0.14.0
cachetools==5.5.0
catalogue==2.0.10
certifi==2024.8.30
cffi==1.17.1
chardet==5.2.0
charset-normalizer==3.3.2
chex==0.1.86
clarabel==0.9.0
click==8.1.7
cloudpathlib==0.19.0
cloudpickle==2.2.1
cmake==3.30.3
cmdstanpy==1.2.4
colorcet==3.1.0
colorlover==0.3.0
colour==0.1.5
community==1.0.0b1
confection==0.1.5
cons==0.4.6
contextlib2==21.6.0
contourpy==1.3.0
cryptography==43.0.1
cuda-python==12.2.1
cudf-cu12==24.4.1
cufflinks==0.17.3
cupy-cuda12x==12.2.0
cvxopt==1.3.2
cvxpy==1.5.3
cycler==0.12.1
cymem==2.0.8
dask==2024.8.0
datascience==0.17.6
db-dtypes==1.3.0
debugpy==1.6.6
decorator==4.4.2
defusedxml==0.7.1
distributed==2024.8.0
dlib==19.24.2
dm-tree==0.1.8
docstring-parser==0.16
docutils==0.18.1
dopamine-rl==4.0.9
duckdb==1.1.0
earthengine-api==1.0.0
easydict==1.13
ecos==2.0.14
editdistance==0.8.1
eerepr==0.0.4
einops==0.8.0
en-core-web-sm==3.7.1
entrypoints==0.4
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
etils==1.9.4
etuples==0.3.9
eval-type-backport==0.2.0
exceptiongroup==1.2.2
fastai==2.7.17
fastcore==1.7.8
fastdownload==0.0.7
fastjsonschema==2.20.0
fastprogress==1.0.3
fastrlock==0.8.2
filelock==3.16.1
firebase-admin==6.5.0
flatbuffers==24.3.25
flax==0.8.5
folium==0.17.0
fonttools==4.53.1
frozendict==2.4.4
frozenlist==1.4.1
fsspec==2024.6.1
future==1.0.0
gast==0.6.0
gcsfs==2024.6.1
gdown==5.2.0
geemap==0.34.3
gensim==4.3.3
geocoder==1.38.1
geographiclib==2.0
geopandas==1.0.1
geopy==2.4.1
gin-config==0.5.0
glob2==0.7
google==2.0.3
google-ai-generativelanguage==0.6.6
google-api-core==2.19.2
google-api-python-client==2.137.0
google-auth==2.27.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.2.0
google-auth-oauthlib==1.2.1
google-cloud-aiplatform==1.67.1
google-cloud-bigquery==3.25.0
google-cloud-bigquery-connection==1.15.5
google-cloud-bigquery-storage==2.26.0
google-cloud-bigtable==2.26.0
google-cloud-core==2.4.1
google-cloud-datastore==2.19.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.16.1
google-cloud-functions==1.16.5
google-cloud-iam==2.15.2
google-cloud-language==2.13.4
google-cloud-pubsub==2.23.1
google-cloud-resource-manager==1.12.5
google-cloud-storage==2.8.0
google-cloud-translate==3.15.5
google-colab==1.0.0
google-crc32c==1.6.0
google-generativeai==0.7.2
google-pasta==0.2.0
google-resumable-media==2.7.2
googleapis-common-protos==1.65.0
googledrivedownloader==0.4
graphviz==0.20.3
greenlet==3.1.1
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.13.1
grpcio==1.64.1
grpcio-status==1.48.2
gspread==6.0.2
gspread-dataframe==3.3.1
gym==0.25.2
gym-notices==0.0.8
h5netcdf==1.3.0
h5py==3.11.0
holidays==0.57
holoviews==1.19.1
html5lib==1.1
httpimport==1.4.0
httplib2==0.22.0
huggingface-hub==0.24.7
humanize==4.10.0
hyperopt==0.2.7
ibis-framework==9.2.0
idna==3.10
imageio==2.35.1
imageio-ffmpeg==0.5.1
imagesize==1.4.1
imbalanced-learn==0.12.3
imgaug==0.4.0
immutabledict==4.2.0
importlib-metadata==8.5.0
importlib-resources==6.4.5
imutils==0.5.4
inflect==7.4.0
iniconfig==2.0.0
intel-cmplr-lib-ur==2024.2.1
intel-openmp==2024.2.1
ipyevents==2.0.2
ipyfilechooser==0.6.0
ipykernel==5.5.6
ipyleaflet==0.19.2
ipyparallel==8.8.0
ipython==7.34.0
ipython-genutils==0.2.0
ipython-sql==0.5.0
ipytree==0.2.2
ipywidgets==7.7.1
itsdangerous==2.2.0
jax==0.4.33
jax-cuda12-pjrt==0.4.33
jax-cuda12-plugin==0.4.33
jaxlib==0.4.33
jellyfish==1.1.0
jieba==0.42.1
jinja2==3.1.4
joblib==1.4.2
jsonpickle==3.3.0
jsonschema==4.23.0
jsonschema-specifications==2023.12.1
jupyter-client==6.1.12
jupyter-console==6.1.0
jupyter-core==5.7.2
jupyter-leaflet==0.19.2
jupyter-server==1.24.0
jupyterlab-pygments==0.3.0
jupyterlab-widgets==3.0.13
kaggle==1.6.17
kagglehub==0.3.0
keras==3.4.1
kiwisolver==1.4.7
langcodes==3.4.0
language-data==1.2.0
lazy-loader==0.4
libclang==18.1.1
librosa==0.10.2.post1
lightgbm==4.5.0
linkify-it-py==2.0.3
llvmlite==0.43.0
locket==1.0.0
logical-unification==0.4.6
lxml==4.9.4
marisa-trie==1.2.0
markdown-it-py==3.0.0
matplotlib==3.7.1
matplotlib-inline==0.1.7
matplotlib-venn==1.1.1
mdit-py-plugins==0.4.2
mdurl==0.1.2
miniKanren==1.0.3
missingno==0.5.2
mistune==0.8.4
mizani==0.11.4
mkl==2024.2.2
ml-dtypes==0.4.1
mlxtend==0.23.1
more-itertools==10.5.0
moviepy==1.0.3
mpmath==1.3.0
msgpack==1.0.8
multidict==6.1.0
multipledispatch==1.0.0
multitasking==0.0.11
murmurhash==1.0.10
music21==9.1.0
namex==0.0.8
natsort==8.4.0
nbclassic==1.1.0
nbclient==0.10.0
nbconvert==6.5.4
nbformat==5.10.4
nest-asyncio==1.6.0
networkx==3.3
nibabel==5.2.1
nltk==3.8.1
notebook==6.5.5
notebook-shim==0.2.4
numba==0.60.0
numexpr==2.10.1
numpy==1.26.4
nvidia-cublas-cu12==12.6.1.4
nvidia-cuda-cupti-cu12==12.6.68
nvidia-cuda-nvcc-cu12==12.6.68
nvidia-cuda-runtime-cu12==12.6.68
nvidia-cudnn-cu12==9.4.0.58
nvidia-cufft-cu12==11.2.6.59
nvidia-cusolver-cu12==11.6.4.69
nvidia-cusparse-cu12==12.5.3.3
nvidia-nccl-cu12==2.23.4
nvidia-nvjitlink-cu12==12.6.68
nvtx==0.2.10
oauth2client==4.1.3
oauthlib==3.2.2
opencv-contrib-python==4.10.0.84
opencv-python==4.10.0.84
opencv-python-headless==4.10.0.84
openpyxl==3.1.5
opt-einsum==3.3.0
optax==0.2.3
optree==0.12.1
orbax-checkpoint==0.6.4
osqp==0.6.7.post0
packaging==24.1
pandas==2.1.4
pandas-datareader==0.10.0
pandas-gbq==0.23.1
pandas-stubs==2.1.4.231227
pandocfilters==1.5.1
panel==1.4.5
param==2.1.1
parso==0.8.4
parsy==2.1
partd==1.4.2
pathlib==1.0.1
patsy==0.5.6
peewee==3.17.6
pexpect==4.9.0
pickleshare==0.7.5
pillow==10.4.0
pip==24.1.2
pip-tools==7.4.1
platformdirs==4.3.6
plotly==5.24.1
plotnine==0.13.6
pluggy==1.5.0
polars==1.6.0
pooch==1.8.2
portpicker==1.5.2
prefetch-generator==1.0.3
preshed==3.0.9
prettytable==3.11.0
proglog==0.1.10
progressbar2==4.5.0
prometheus-client==0.21.0
promise==2.3
prompt-toolkit==3.0.47
prophet==1.1.5
proto-plus==1.24.0
protobuf==3.20.3
psutil==5.9.5
psycopg2==2.9.9
ptyprocess==0.7.0
py4j==0.10.9.7
pyOpenSSL==24.2.1
py-cpuinfo==9.0.0
pyarrow==14.0.2
pyarrow-hotfix==0.6
pyasn1==0.6.1
pyasn1-modules==0.4.1
pycocotools==2.0.8
pycparser==2.22
pydantic==2.9.2
pydantic-core==2.23.4
pydata-google-auth==1.8.2
pydot==3.0.1
pydot-ng==2.0.0
pydotplus==2.0.2
pyerfa==2.0.1.4
pygame==2.6.0
pygments==2.18.0
pymc==5.16.2
pymystem3==0.2.0
pynvjitlink-cu12==0.3.0
pyogrio==0.9.0
pyparsing==3.1.4
pyperclip==1.9.0
pyproj==3.6.1
pyproject-hooks==1.1.0
pyshp==2.3.1
pytensor==2.25.4
pytest==7.4.4
python-apt==2.4.0
python-box==7.2.0
python-dateutil==2.8.2
python-louvain==0.16
python-slugify==8.0.4
python-utils==3.8.2
pytz==2024.2
pyviz-comms==3.0.3
pyzmq==24.0.1
qdldl==0.1.7.post4
ratelim==0.1.6
referencing==0.35.1
regex==2024.9.11
requests==2.32.3
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
requirements-parser==0.9.0
rich==13.8.1
rmm-cu12==24.4.0
rpds-py==0.20.0
rpy2==3.4.2
rsa==4.9
safetensors==0.4.5
scikit-image==0.24.0
scikit-learn==1.5.2
scipy==1.13.1
scooby==0.10.0
scs==3.2.7
seaborn==0.13.1
sentencepiece==0.2.0
setuptools==71.0.4
shapely==2.0.6
shellingham==1.5.4
simple-parsing==0.1.6
six==1.16.0
sklearn-pandas==2.2.0
smart-open==7.0.4
sniffio==1.3.1
snowballstemmer==2.2.0
sortedcontainers==2.4.0
soundfile==0.12.1
soupsieve==2.6
soxr==0.5.0.post1
spacy==3.7.6
spacy-legacy==3.0.12
spacy-loggers==1.0.5
sphinxcontrib-applehelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp==2.1.0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath==1.0.1
sphinxcontrib-qthelp==2.0.0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml==2.0.0
sqlglot==25.1.0
sqlparse==0.5.1
srsly==2.4.8
stanio==0.5.1
statsmodels==0.14.3
sympy==1.13.3
tables==3.8.0
tabulate==0.9.0
tbb==2021.13.1
tblib==3.0.0
tenacity==9.0.0
tensorboard==2.17.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.7.2
tensorflow==2.17.0
tensorflow-datasets==4.9.6
tensorflow-hub==0.16.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.37.1
tensorflow-metadata==1.15.0
tensorflow-probability==0.24.0
tensorstore==0.1.65
termcolor==2.4.0
terminado==0.18.1
text-unidecode==1.3
textblob==0.17.1
tf-keras==2.17.0
tf-slim==1.1.0
thinc==8.2.5
threadpoolctl==3.5.0
tifffile==2024.9.20
tinycss2==1.3.0
tokenizers==0.19.1
toml==0.10.2
tomli==2.0.1
toolz==0.12.1
torch==2.4.1+cu121
torchaudio==2.4.1+cu121
torchsummary==1.5.1
torchvision==0.19.1+cu121
tornado==6.3.3
tqdm==4.66.5
traitlets==5.7.1
traittypes==0.2.1
transformers==4.44.2
tweepy==4.14.0
typeguard==4.3.0
typer==0.12.5
types-pytz==2024.2.0.20240913
types-setuptools==75.1.0.20240917
typing-extensions==4.12.2
tzdata==2024.1
tzlocal==5.2
uc-micro-py==1.0.3
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==2.2.3
vega-datasets==0.9.0
wasabi==1.1.3
wcwidth==0.2.13
weasel==0.4.1
webcolors==24.8.0
webencodings==0.5.1
websocket-client==1.8.0
werkzeug==3.0.4
wheel==0.44.0
widgetsnbextension==3.6.9
wordcloud==1.9.3
wrapt==1.16.0
xarray==2024.9.0
xarray-einstats==0.8.0
xgboost==2.1.1
xlrd==2.0.1
xyzservices==2024.9.0
yarl==1.11.1
yellowbrick==1.5
yfinance==0.2.43
zict==3.0.0
zipp==3.20.2
PyGObject==3.42.1
SecretStorage==3.3.1
blinker==1.4
dbus-python==1.2.18
distro==1.7.0
jeepney==0.7.1
keyring==23.5.0
launchpadlib==1.10.16
lazr.restfulclient==0.14.4
lazr.uri==1.0.6
wadllib==1.3.6
autocommand==2.2.2
backports.tarfile==1.2.0
jaraco.context==5.3.0
jaraco.functools==4.0.1
jaraco.text==3.12.1
ordered-set==4.1.0


It's unclear what you mean when you say it "no longer works". What error are you seeing? Also, you mention installing JAX v0.4.23, but the second set of packages lists JAX v0.4.33. Did the installation fail?
